# How do I define spring.config.name for Spring Boot tests?

Tags: spring-boot, configuration, spring-boot-test

I have a Spring Boot Application with a custom configuration setup like this:

```
src/main/resources
├── application.properties
├── config1
│   ├── application-dev.properties
│   ├── application-prod.properties
│   └── application.properties
├── config2
│   ├── application-dev.properties
│   ├── application-prod.properties
│   └── application.properties
└── config3
    ├── application-dev.properties
    ├── application-prod.properties
    └── application.properties
```

with config to use specified at runtime as:

```sh
java -jar \
-Dspring.profiles.active=dev \
-Dspring.config.name=application,config1/application \
target/my-application.0.0.1.jar
```

How do I specify this for a `@SpringBootTest`? I tried using `@TestPropertySources` but it doesn't work:

```java
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("prod")
@TestPropertySources({
        @TestPropertySource("classpath:application.properties"),
        @TestPropertySource("classpath:application-${spring.profile.active}.properties"),
        @TestPropertySource("classpath:config1/application.properties"),
        @TestPropertySource("classpath:config1/application-${spring.profile.active}.properties"),
        @TestPropertySource("classpath:config2/application.properties"),
        @TestPropertySource("classpath:config2/application-${spring.profile.active}.properties"),
        @TestPropertySource("classpath:config3/application.properties"),
        @TestPropertySource("classpath:config3/application-${spring.profile.active}.properties")
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot allows specifying properties in both `@SpringBootTest` & `@TestPropertySource`, which can be leveraged to specify the `spring.config.name` property. The following, for example, loads all configs with `dev` profile:

```java
@SpringBootTest(properties = {
        "spring.config.name=config1/application,config2/application,config3/application,application"
})
@ActiveProfiles("dev")
```

This most likely works as these properties take high precedence in the order specified [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config).